# Using S3 bucket as a file server for the public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

#### Use-case

We basically want to collect files from external customers into a file server.

**We were thinking of using the S3 bucket as the file server that customers can interact with directly.**

#### Question

Is it possible to accomplish this where we create a bucket for each customer, and he can be given a link to the S3 bucket that also serves as the UI for him to drag and drop his files into directly?

1. He shouldn't have to log-in to AWS or create an AWS account
2. He should directly interact with **only** his S3 bucket (drag-drop, add, delete files), there shouldn't be a way for him to check other buckets. We will probably create many S3 buckets for our customers in the same AWS account. His entry point into the S3 bucket UI is via a link (S3 bucket URL perhaps)

If such a thing is possible - would love some general pointers as to what more I should do (see my approach below)

#### My work so far

1. I've been able to create an S3 bucket - grant public access
2. Set policies to Get, List and PutObject into the S3 bucket.
3. I've been able to give public access to objects inside the bucket using their link, but never their bucket itself.

Is there something more I can build on or am I hitting a dead-end and this is not possible to accomplish?

P.S: This may not be a coding question, but maybe your answer could have code to accomplish it if at all possible, general pointers if possible

Comment: Haven you asked that already few hours ago?

Answer (score 0):

S3 presigned url can help in such cases, but you have write your own custom frontend application for drag and drop features.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html